# Como copiar os filhos de um nó para outro nó - Android com Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Tenho um banco X que contém categorias de empresas e  quero que ao inserir os dados manualmente  em Categorias,  envia uma cópia para AllEmpresas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando esse código porém não estou encontrando uma forma de pegar apenas os filhos

```
private void copyRecord(DatabaseReference fromPath, final DatabaseReference toPath) {
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {   

               toPath.setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isComplete()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Success!");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Copy failed!");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };

        fromPath.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro que você faça essa cópia através de uma [Cloud Function](https://medium.com/@rosariopfernandes/firebase-cloud-functions-f6ed3787fa8d). Isso porque as Cloud Functions são executadas na Cloud, enquanto que o seu código irá correr no dispositivo do utilizador. E se o utilizador fechar a app antes da cópia terminar? Você terá o banco com dados em falta ou incorrectos.

Veja [Como começar a utilizar as Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/@rosariopfernandes/fcf-comecar-32c984dbc12) e a sua função ficaria assim:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin'); //Importar o Admin SDK para escrever dados na database
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.copiarEmpresas = functions.database.ref('/Categorias/{categoria}/{empresa}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {
        var snapshot = change.after;
        return admin.database().ref('AllEmpresas').child(snapshot.key).set(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: essa função vou ter que criar para cada empresa? ou vai copiar todos os filhos de academia, alimentação etc?

Comment: Vai copiar todos filhos de cada categoria. Essa é a única função que você vai criar.

Comment: Tu é o cara! Muito obrigado!